# Running Selenium on Shared Hosting Cpanel Terminal

Tags: python, selenium, cpanel

I am using a selenium python script with chrome webdriver to scrape some data from a website. The script is working fine in my windows 10 machine however I don't have any idea how to run the script in my shared hosting cpanel from termial. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

My script:

```
import requests
import io
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("user-agent=Chrome/80.0.3987.132")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)

with open("links.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as a_file:
    for line in a_file:
        stripped_line = line.strip()
        driver.get(stripped_line)
        
        file1=open('data.txt','a')
        time.sleep(15)
        html_source=driver.page_source
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html_source,'lxml')

        #finding all images
        images=soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'style-module--action--1Avvt'})

        for image in images:
            #for each image append the src attribute to links.txt
            file1.write(str(image.findAll('a')))
            file1.write('\n')

        file1.close()

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Your shared hosting service provides a shell in their cpanel?  That's dangerous.  If you can install all of the Python packages you need, you can run the application, but why would you?  Why not run it locally?

Comment: The process is taking too much time and my internet speed is really very slow sometimes. If I can run it there it will be very helpful and I can focus on some other task

Comment: If you can ssh into your shared hosting service, then this is pretty easy.  But if you are literally typing into a shell in your browser, it all depends on what the hosting service allows.  If you can run "pip" to install packages, then you're good.

Comment: I can run ssh but don't know the process of installing the package

Comment: It's the exact same process you used to install on your local system.  `pip`.